# Firebase Using orderBy with endAt

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
"-MSxxx": {
        "category": "Firuit",
        "isBeverage": true,
        "title": "Orange"
    },
    "-MQxxx": {
        "category": "Firuit",
        "isBeverage": false,
        "title": "Orange Juice"
    },
```

I have data like the output above. **I load new data as the scrolls using the endAt () and limitToLast parameters.**

Firebase does not allow me to use orderBy and endAt () parameters together. orderBy = "isBeverage" & equalTo = true & endAt = "- MSxxx" & limitToLast = 10.

I am having a problem when I make an inquiry by the client. Since I have listed the last 10 topics, I cannot make a healthy listing if drinks are not included in that listing.

How can I use it this way?

Comment: Which API are you using? The Javascript SDK, the REST API, etc

Comment: Firebase Real Time Database - ReactJS (Javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with using `orderBy` and `endAt` together, but using `equalTo` and `endAt` together.

`startAt`, `equalTo`, and `endAt`, all accept a second parameter that is the key of their respective results. `orderByChild("isBeverage").startAt(true, "-MQ")` reads as: get all children where `isBeverage` is `true`, but the key of the children must be equal to or greater than `-MQ`.

If you wanted to get all children with a `isBeverage` value that is `true`, up to the child with the key `-MSxxx`, you can use the following query:

```
const query = firebase.database()
  .ref('/path/to/data')
  .orderByChild("isBeverage")
  .startAt(true /* startAt value for isBeverage */)
  .endAt(true /* endAt value for isBeverage */, "-MSxxx" /* key of last result */)
```

If you wanted to get all children with a `isBeverage` value that is `true`, with a key that starts with `-MS`, you would use:

```
const query = firebase.database()
  .ref('/path/to/data')
  .orderByChild("isBeverage")
  .startAt(true, "-MS")
  .endAt(true, "-MS\uf8ff")
```